# How to know a messages format for different Minecraft servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there some way to get a messages format for Minecraft server, if I'm not a owner this server?

I'm trying to understand what the format is to extract from a chat line: receiver nickname, sender nickname, message, rank and etc.

For example, in the server **cubecraft.net**

- [CHAT] :Stone: SomeNickName: hello
- [CHAT] :Stone: SomeNickName: SomeNickName2 hello
- [CHAT] Me -> :Stone: SomeNickName: hello

**tcpshield.pvplegacy.net**

- [CHAT]  hello
- [CHAT]  SomeNickName2 hello
- [CHAT] [You -> SomeNickName] check something
- [CHAT] [SomeNickName-> You] waht

How can I know the format per server? And additional how can I discern between nickname and part of message, like here: [CHAT]  SomeNickName2 hello (SomeNickName2 can be nickname and can be part of a message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl; dr, you can’t.

In Java Edition, servers send messages to clients in JSON format.  These can contain any content, any formatting data, anything.  The client simply shows this to the user.

Comment: But each server has a specific format (like log4j.xml), no? I can access this format and learn from there what will be the format of a message?

Comment: the server can send whatever it wants in the JSON, different plugins can use different formats, etc. there’s no good way to detect it